# How to detect usage of app with webview (iOS & Android) on Google Analytics?

Tags: android, ios, webview, google-analytics

I have an iOS and Android app, both using webviews to show some pages from a webshop. The webshop itself has Google Analytics to track events.

I can see all the data when I go to Browser & operating system, I see the sessions, users, transactions, conversion ratio per browser. The problem I'm having is that is shows `Safari (in-app)` and `Android Webview`. Most of this traffic will probably be from my apps but from what I've read this is also traffic that for example visits the webshop within the Facebook app. Is this how it works?

And what is the best practice for my apps to have their own segment that will show me the sessions, users, transactions & conversion ratio? I want to have clear numbers for all those segments so I can be 100% sure all that traffic is from my apps only.

**EDIT**
I don't have access to the website code so I can't add GA code

Comment: Please take a look at suggestion how GA can be implemented for hybrid mobile apps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28953605/how-to-implement-google-analytics-in-hybrid-mobile-apps

Comment: But they are not hybrid apps, native apps with a webview.

Answer (score 0):

You can have communication between WebView and App through Javascript. You can pass the event and data to app, which app can push to any analytics platform for you to see.

Also, you can get natively webview call backs in delegate method which you can track.

There are several third party tools like for iOS : https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge available which do this good.

Comment: But will I get all the data I want with those Javascript Bridges? Also the transactions, conversion etc or only the events I'm logging myself?

Comment: What do you mean by all the data? You can always send data at different points during transactions, conversions from your web view through java script bridges to the app....
Also log the same events directly through your web pages.....
So, you will have access to both the app data numbers and total numbers(from all sources where web page is opened including fb).....
I have been doing it in my app successfully...